# Backbone view, needs to render an image in the template depending on params

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, templates, backbone.js, jst

So I have a view that is going to render a template that will include an image. This image is dependent on the variable being passed in, located in **assets/images**.

Basically, how can I pass in this model into the template so it can render the correct image?

Normally in `Rails` I would just do in a Rails `ERB` Template:

```
<img class="item-portrait" 
src="<%= image_path("items/" + item.name.gsub(" ", "-").downcase + ".png")
 %>">
```

How can I accomplish the same effect in a `JST` template?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume your model looks like this :

```
var itemPortraitModel = new Backbone.Model({
  'path' : 'path_to_file'
});
```

and your view is similar to this :

```
var ItemPortraitView = Backbone.View.extend({
  template: JST['itemPortraitTemplate'],
  render: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.attributes));
    return this;
  }
});
```

then in your itemPortraitTemplate template code, any of the properties in your model will be available:

```
<img class="item-portrait" 
src="<% print(("items/" + path + ".png") %>">
```

Comment: I don't think this works. print doesn't seem to do the same exact thing as image_path. It tries to send me to a localhost route

Comment: print just outputs the arguments to the screen, it doesn't manipulate it like image_path (which I'm not familiar with). You can either make sure the path is already correct in the model or pass a helper function into the template which correctly manipulates it. It may help if you show an example of what your model looks like and what the correct file paths would be.